# Davies MSP430 Software Debounce Question

Tags: msp430

currently working on software button debounce. Using Davies MSP430 book. I am trying to write similar code in C (using CCS) for a MSP430FR6989. The program uses bit shifting, and I understand idea of it. What I cannot figure out is how to deceipher these #defines that Davies uses. I don't know how to convert that for the FR6989. I keep getting errors that I have undefined items.

Like I define RAW_BUTTON_PRESS1 as P1IN_bit.P1IN_1 and am getting errors that P1IN_bit is undefined. I'm having trouble understanding these pin assignment conversions

snippet from davies

[image]

my code

```
// Device: FR6989
// See Davies MSP430 Software Debounce starting on pg 233

#include <msp430.h>
#include <intrinsics.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union debounce{
unsigned char debounceP1IN;
struct  {
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_0 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_1 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_2 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_3 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_4 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_5 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_6 : 1;
    unsigned char debounceP1IN_7 : 1;
} debounceP1IN_bit;
};


#define RAW_BUTTON_PRESS1        P1IN_bit.P1IN_1
#define DEBOUNCE_BUTTON_PRESS1   debounceP1IN_bit.debounceP1IN_1
#define LED1                    P1OUT_bit.P1OUT_0

void main (void)
{
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;               // stop watchdog timer
PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;                   // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode

P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                     //Pre-load LED P1.0 Off
P1DIR |= BIT0;                      //Set P1.0 LED to output

P1DIR &= ~BIT1;                    //set P1.1 button to input
P1REN |= BIT1;                     //Enable Resistor Button P1.1
P1OUT |= BIT1;                     //Set as Pullup resistor Button P1.1

debounceP1IN = 0xFF;                //initialize debounce state of P1.1
TA0CCR0 = 5000;                     // TA0 interrupt triggers every 5 ms
TA0CCTL0 |= CCIE;                   //Enable TA0 interrupt
TA0CTL |= (TASSEL_2 + MC_1 + TACLR);    //SMCLK (1mhz) count to CCR0, clear timer

__enable_interrupt();

for(;;)
{
   LED1 = DEBOUNCE_BUTTON_PRESS1; //Update LED1 from debounced button
}
}

#define PRESS_THRESHOLD     0x3F
#define RELEASE_THRESHOLD   0xFC

#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void TA0_ISR (void)
{
   static unsigned char P11ShiftReg = 0xFF; // Shift Reg for history of P1.1

P11ShiftReg >>= 1;                      // Update history in shift register
if (RAW_BUTTON_PRESS1 == 1)                         //Insert latest input from P1.1
{
    P11ShiftReg |= BIT7;                //Set MSB of Shiftreg P1.1 to 1
}

if (DEBOUNCE_BUTTON_PRESS1 == 0)                         //when debounce value is low
{
    if(P11ShiftReg >= RELEASE_THRESHOLD)    //when button is released
    {
        DEBOUNCE_BUTTON_PRESS1 = 1;                          //set new debounce state high
    }
}
else if(P11ShiftReg <= PRESS_THRESHOLD)     //when debounce value is high and button is pressed
    {
        DEBOUNCE_BUTTON_PRESS1 = 0;                          //set new debounce state low
    }
}
```

Comment: you are basically looking for successive states with  change to exceed expected bounce time which depends on mechanical spring durations which vary from 1 to 100ms

Comment: I think you are taking code that was designed to operate with a different C compiler and ignorantly expecting similar code to operate with CCS, as well. The _bit stuff DOES NOT work with CCS. You already are doing the right things under CCS, using bit operations in C, for other registers. So you know HOW to do it right. Just read the things that are causing you trouble, use your head about what was probably meant with the other C compiler, and recode those parts using CCS style coding. Don't expect copy and paste between C compilers to "just work right."

Comment: I just dont know how to handle the DebP2IN_bit.DebP2IN_1, like how do I convert that into a CCS syntax to set LED 1 in the forever loop? LED1 and RAWB1 I can easily change. Like RAWB1 == 1 would be !(P1IN & BIT1), idk how to do the DebP2IN